# Inter aural time difference generation using sine waves

Tags: sound

I have a stereo sound for Inter  aural time difference consisting of sine wave(16 samples as 16 bit PCM Data) for left and right audio. From time to time I would like to advance either the left or right audio so that sound in one ear comes earlier than the other. If I just put another sine wave of different frequency in between my normal sine samples to give an illusion of changing sound in one ear, I hear a click. I am playing a buffer of 1024 samples at a time containing looped sine wave samples. If I drop one sample it generates a click as well. Can someone suggest a way of speeding up the Sine wave without generating a click. 
e.g loop the sine wave separately for both ears. Now advance the sine wave in one ear so that it feels like a frequency change and then play the normal sound again in both ears. I have fixed sine samples with me. (I work in java so can't do any heavy computations). I have tried to clarify but the question could still be confusing. Ask for specific details.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I understand the point.
If you are outputting signal[i] you cant jump to signal[i+n] instantaneously.
You should just fade it to the new point with some window function. Allow some period of fading time.

For example: If I currently output signal[i] and I want to shift it to signal[i+n] in 1 second. I will use half of Hann window to fade it in and out. So I time scaling Hann from pi to 1 second.
and output $signal[i+n]*Hann[i]+signal[i]*(1-Hann[i])$ for 1 second before I switch to signal[i+n] at full scale. This should not generate a click.

You may want to try other window function or different fading period.